# HTTP HEAD method and pipelining

Tags: http, http-headers, pipelining

I'm writing some code that parses HTTP requests and responses, but it may not see both sides of every conversation.

The [HTTP RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.4) states that a `HEAD` request should cause exactly the same response as `GET` except that a message body is not sent. This seems to imply that a `Content-Length` header would be included.

If [HTTP Pipelining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining) is being used, I cannot see how you would reliably parse a pipelined response to a `HEAD` without having seen the request; the headers would not correctly indicate the length of the response, there is no `Transfer-Encoding`, and the connection would not necessarily be closed at the end.

Any ideas? Can anyone see any other types of response that cannot be parsed without seeing the request?

Answer (score 3):

I agree. It is not possible to know that the response to the request does not have an entity body, even though the ContentLength header seems to imply the opposite. All implementations should take the request method into account for this reason.